# Busca de produto por nome e marca

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho duas tabelas, uma chamada *marcas* com as marcas dos produtos e outra chamada *produtos*. Dentro dessa tabela *produtos* tem camisas, calças e etc. Quero que ao fazer uma busca, por exemplo "camisa Hollister", ele retorne todas as camisas com a marca Hollister. alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
Table `produto` (
  `item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `item_slug` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `item_brand_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`)
) 

ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1432 ;

TABLE `marcas` (
  `item_brand_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_brand_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `item_brand_slug` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `item_brand_image` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `item_brand_color` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ffffff',
  `item_brand_priority` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_brand_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=319 ;
```

Comment: Você pode descrever suas tabelas aqui na linguagem `SQL`?

Comment: Cigano Morrison Mendez, como pode ver, eu pego o id da tabela marcas e coloco no produto.

Comment: Eu sugiro que você crie índices nos campos que estarão sujeitos à busca, por questões de performance. Como você não está usando chaves estrangeiras, pode trocar a engine pra MyISAM e usar full text indexes.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos, mas FULL TEXT não funciona na versão do mysql que estou utilizando. conhece algum outro método?

Comment: Qual a versão que você usa?

Answer (score 3):

## Preparar os dados

Primeiro precisas preparar os dados que o utilizador te fornece, ou seja, quer seja indicado `camisa Hollister` ou `Hollister camisa`, deverás encontrar resultados assumindo que a marca e o produto existem:

```php
$search_term = "camisa Hollister";

$search_arr = explode(' ', $search_term);

$append_produtos = "";
$append_marcas = "";
foreach ($search_arr as $term) {
    $append_produtos.= "p.item_name LIKE '%".$term."%' OR ";
    $append_marcas.= "m.item_brand_name LIKE '%".$term."%' OR ";
}
```

## Consulta

Agora que temos os termos de pesquisa fornecidos preparados para aplicar na nossa consulta, vamos preparar a mesma relacionando as duas tabelas, recolhendo apenas registos da tabela `produtos` que tem uma relação com a tabela `marca` através da coluna `item_brand_id`:

```php
$query = "SELECT p.* FROM produtos p
INNER JOIN marcas m ON (m.item_brand_id = p.item_brand_id)
WHERE (".rtrim($append_produtos, "OR ").") AND (".rtrim($append_marcas, "OR ").")";
```

## Explicação

A consulta ficaria da seguinte forma:

```sql
SELECT p.* FROM produtos p
INNER JOIN marcas m ON (m.item_brand_id = p.item_brand_id)
WHERE (p.item_name LIKE '%camisa%' OR p.item_name LIKE '%Hollister%')
AND (m.item_brand_name LIKE '%camisa%' OR m.item_brand_name LIKE '%Hollister%')
```

O que está a ser feito é consultar todos os registos na tabela `produtos` que contenham um valor na coluna `item_brand_id` que seja igual ao valor da coluna `item_brand_id` da tabela `marcas` onde o registo na tabela `marcas` contenha alguma das palavras fornecidas e o registo na tabela `produto` contenha alguma das palavras fornecidas.

---

Funções utilizadas nesta resposta:

- [PHP rtrim()](http://pt1.php.net/rtrim) - Para remover algo na extrema direita da *string*
- [PHP foreach()](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) - Para percorrer uma matriz e realizar operações por cada entrada
- [PHP explode()](http://pt1.php.net/explode) - Para converter uma *string* numa matriz

Comment: Acho que no fim das contas o ideal seria usar um índice FULLTEXT, para conseguir lidar com buscas como "camisas Hollister".

Comment: @bfavaretto, mas FULLTEXT é só em versões novas do mysql, na antiga como seria?

Comment: @Zuul, até funcionou, porém se eu buscar camisa regata,  regata não é marca, iria dar erro!

Comment: @LeandroCosta Fiz a resposta de cabeça, mas não estou a ver que erro é que possa originar dai. Resultados fora do pretendido isso sim é possível, tudo depende da informação nas tabelas. Se puderes elaborar a tua pergunta com mais detalhes sobre os dados nas tabelas, pode ser que dê para optimizar a consulta.

Comment: @LeandroCosta Eu achava que o MySQL já tinha suporte a FULLTEXT há um bom tempo, não?

Comment: Não, é só na versão mais recente!

Comment: @LeandroCosta Verifiquei e na verdade tem suporte faz tempo em tabelas MyISAM. Mas as suas são InnoDB, e nesse caso o suporte é mesmo mais recente.

Comment: @bfavaretto, entendi obrigado pela informação!

Answer (score 1):

A maior dificuldade é [preparar a cláusula "LIKE" apropriadamente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3683868/370290), uma vez que o usuário pode digitar "%" ou outros caracteres com significado especial na sua pesquisa.

```
function like($string, $e)
{
    return str_replace(array($e, '_', '%'), array($e.$e, $e.'_', $e.'%'), $string);
}

function like_clauses($campo, $termos)
{
    $clauses = array();

    foreach ($termos as $termo)
    {
        $clause = 
            '(' . $campo
            . ' LIKE "%'
            . mysqli_real_escape_string(like($termo, '='))
            . '%" ESCAPE "=")';

        $clauses[] = $clause;
    }

    return $clauses;
}
```

Podemos usar a função `like_clauses` acima, informando o nome do campo para pesquisa e uma lista de palavras (termos), para obter as respectivas cláusulas "LIKE" apropriadamente formatadas.

```
function minha_busca($busca)
{
    $termos = array();

    foreach (explode(' ', $busca) as $palavra)
    {
        $termo = trim($palavra);

        if (!empty($termo))
        {
            $termos[] = $termo;
        }
    }

    $termos = array_unique($termos);

    if (empty($termos))
    {
        return array();
    }

    // até aqui apenas limpamos a entrada
    // garantindo a existência de pelo menos um termo de busca

    $sql = sprintf(
        'SELECT item_brand_id FROM marcas WHERE %s',
        implode(' OR ', like_clauses('item_brand_name', $termos))
    );

    // com este primeiro SELECT, obtemos as MARCAS

    $brand_ids = array();

    /* rodar SQL, fazer loop nos resultados, incluir os item_brand_ids em $brand_ids */

    $sql = sprintf(
        'SELECT * FROM produto WHERE %s AND (%s)',
        empty($brand_ids) ? 'TRUE' : 'item_brand_id IN (' . implode(', ', $brand_ids) . ')',
        implode(' OR ', like_clauses('item_name', $termos))
    );

    // com este segundo SELECT, obtemos os produtos, restringidos (ou não) pelas marcas

    $produtos = array();

    /* rodar SQL, fazer loop nos resultados, incluir os registros em $produtos */

    return $produtos;
}
```

Para usar a função `minha_busca` acima, e conferir os resultados:

```
$busca = $_POST['busca'];

$resultado = minha_busca($busca);

print_r($resultado);
```

---

***Observações***:

- O uso de `mysqli_real_escape_string` assume que a extensão `mysqli` está em uso, com uma conexão ativa.
- Na função `minha_busca` ainda é preciso preencher o código que executa os SQL e faz os *loops* nos resultados.

Comment: Dependendo do caso, pode ser necessário `AND` em vez `OR` entre os `LIKE`s.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o operador SQL LIKE. Dependendo de como está suas tabelas. Vou mostrar um exemplo de como fazer com PHP PDO:

```
public function get_product( $product_name ) {
  $sql  = "SELECT * FROM produto LIKE :product_name";
  $stmt = Connection::prepare( $sql );
  $stmt->execute();

  return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou bem claro. Tu quer o SELECT das tabelas, ou tu quer saber como conectar PHP e banco de dados?

A query será algo mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT * FROM produto 
LEFT JOIN marcas
ON produto.item_brand_id = marcas.item_brand_id
WHERE marcas.item_brand_name = 'Hollister'
AND (não entendi como tu sabe o que é camisa, o que é bermuda, etc. 
Mas aqui iria o critério para ver o que é camisa)
```

Ou pode ser que tu não saiba fazer o php "conversar" com o banco.
Aconselho o uso da documentação.

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-connect.php

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Não, eu gostaria de saber como ficaria uma query, se eu colocasse no input "Camisa Hollister", como ficaria a query para buscar todos produtos camisa que tenha a marca Hollister

Comment: a query está ali. só o "AND camisa" eu não sei como fazer, pois eu não entendi como tu define o que é camisa e o que é outra vestimenta.

Answer (score 0):

Uma ideia que tenho é a seguinte, criar uma view com os dados que precisa, depois quando alguém fizer uma busca, você faz seu `select` nessa view.

Exemplo da view

```
CREATE VIEW `produto_marca` AS
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', p.item_name, m.item_brand_name) as item
FROM produto p
LEFT JOIN marcas m ON m.item_brand_id = p.item_brand_id
```

Exemplo da query

```
SELECT * FROM produto_marca WHERE item LIKE '%camisa hollister%'
```

Lembrando que isso é uma ideia, sendo assim deixei o mais simples possível e na `view` provavelmente você irá precisar de mais campos.